# Mapreduce chaining jobs failing with exception

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am very new to hadoop and I am getting this error while running a mapreduce job. I am trying to calculate the avg for a person and trying to take the input of first job and passing to 2nd job for calculating grades. I understood the problem but I am not able to figure out where I am doing wrong.

Below is the exception:

```
   15/07/02 23:53:36 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
    15/07/02 23:53:36 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
    15/07/02 23:53:38 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201507022153_0026
    15/07/02 23:53:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
    15/07/02 23:53:44 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201507022153_0026_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
    java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable
        at com.hadoop.mrchain.Driver$Mapper2.map(Driver.java:1)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:647)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:323)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:266)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1278)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:260)
```

My code:

```
package com.hadoop.mrchain;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class Driver {
    /*
     * Mapper1
     */
    public static class Mapper1 extends
            Mapper<Object, Text, Text, DoubleWritable> {
        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
            String studentName = itr.nextToken();
            Double marks = Double.parseDouble(itr.nextToken());
            context.write(new Text(studentName), new DoubleWritable(marks));
        }
    }

    /*
     * Mapper1
     */
    public static class Mapper2 extends
            Mapper<Object, DoubleWritable, Text, DoubleWritable> {
        public void map(Object key, DoubleWritable value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
            context.write(new Text(itr.nextToken()), new DoubleWritable(Double
                    .parseDouble(itr.nextToken().toString())));
        }
    }

    /*
     * Reducer1
     */
    public static class Reducer1 extends
            Reducer<Text, DoubleWritable, Text, DoubleWritable> {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<DoubleWritable> values,
                Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int sum = 0;
            int count = 0;
            for (DoubleWritable val : values) {
                sum += val.get();
                count++;
            }
            double avg = sum / count;
            context.write(key, new DoubleWritable(avg));

        }
    }

    /*
     * Reducer2
     */
    public static class Reducer2 extends
            Reducer<Text, DoubleWritable, Text, Text> {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<DoubleWritable> values,
                Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            for (DoubleWritable val : values) {
                // double marks = Double.parseDouble(val.toString());
                int marks = ((Double) val.get()).intValue();
                if (marks >= 70) {
                    context.write(key, new Text("GradeA"));
                } else if (marks >= 60 && marks < 70) {
                    context.write(key, new Text("GradeB"));
                } else if (marks < 60 && marks >= 40) {
                    context.write(key, new Text("GradeC"));
                } else {
                    context.write(key, new Text("FAIL"));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        cleanFileSystem(conf, args);

        Job job1 = new Job(conf, "BATCH51-MRCHAIN-JOB1");
        job1.setJarByClass(Driver.class);

        job1.setMapperClass(Mapper1.class);
        job1.setCombinerClass(Reducer1.class);
        job1.setReducerClass(Reducer1.class);
        job1.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job1.setOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job1, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job1, new Path(args[1]));

        job1.waitForCompletion(true);

        // Job2
        Job job2 = new Job(conf, "BATCH51-MRCHAIN-JOB2");
        job2.setJarByClass(Driver.class);

        job2.setMapperClass(Mapper2.class);
        job2.setCombinerClass(Reducer2.class);
        job2.setReducerClass(Reducer2.class);
        // job2.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        // job2.setMapOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);
        job2.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job2.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job2, new Path(args[1]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, new Path(args[2]));

        System.exit(job2.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }

    private static void cleanFileSystem(Configuration conf, String[] args)
            throws Exception {
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        if (fs.exists(new Path(args[1]))) {
            fs.delete(new Path(args[1]), true);
        }
        if (fs.exists(new Path(args[2]))) {
            fs.delete(new Path(args[2]), true);
        }
        // if (fs.exists(new Path(args[3]))) {
        // fs.delete(new Path(args[3]), true);
        // }
    }
}
```

Sample Input:

```
hello 90
suresh 80
krishna 16
ramesh 55
santosh 82
anji 66
gopal 88
hello99
suresh 80
krishna 16
gopal 91
hello 91
suresh 80
krishna 86
ramesh 55
santosh 82
anji 66
gopal 95
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not able to cast few strings into double, for example hello cannot be casted to double. You need to change you logic in mapper to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues to be addressed in the code posted in question:

1. We need to ensure that second mapper is able to correctly read the output generated by first map-reduce job. As the input format in use is default `TextInputFormat` which reads and store key-value in `LongWritable, Text`. In here, the code is trying to fit value of type `Text` into type `DoubleWritable`. Hence the exception. To fix this we need to ensure `Text` goes into `Text`.
2. As the combiner output goes to the reducer, the given reducer class cannot be used as is for combiner. To explain it; in the given scenario combiner emits `Text, Text`, but this is NOT the type reducer expects its key-values to be.

Below are the changes required to make the code working:

```
Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, DoubleWritable> { //Changed in mapper2 defn
//Changes in Driver main method
job1.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class); //added
job1.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class); //added
//job2.setCombinerClass(Reducer2.class);  //commented
job2.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);   //un-commented
job2.setMapOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class); //un-commented
job2.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class); //added
```

Hope this helps.